# Significado de "alta llanta" en Argentina

Tags: coloquialismos, vocabulario-técnico, argentina

Viendo [este video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAFu8zOpj8I) de Capusotto, supongo que "alta llanta" es un término común en Argentina. ¿Qué significa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alta o alto se usa como sinónimo de buena calidad.

Llanta significa zapatilla (creo que en otros países les dicen "tenis", sería calzado deportivo); ea significado de llanta se llega, creo, por metáfora con la llanta de un auto, que sería el "calzado"; la llanta (una parte de la rueda) a su vez representa en realidad la rueda (el todo), si no me equivoco por metonimia.

Esta expresión y otras similares (alto rancho como sinónimo de buena casa, alto guiso como comida suculenta, etc) son bastante jergales e incluso marginales. Y si bien se han hecho conocidas y se han extendido hacia una comprensión más general, difícilmente se usen sin efecto humorísitico o denostativo fuera de ámbitos más o menos marginales (como es el caso de este video).

Comment: Agrego que las "similares" (alto guiso, alto rancho) son -creo- derivadas, "altas llantas" parece ser la expresión madre (desconozco origen). Además, son muy recientes (5 años?) y, supongo, efímeras.

Answer (score -1):

`Alta yanta` es decir como `alta gora`, `remera`, etc... Como que buena remera. Pero en este caso no te esta hablando de la parte de la rueda. Es como una forma de decir de algunas personas. Es como `alta garca`